# 'Heap corruption detected' crashes in OS X app

Tags: macos, heap-corruption

I'm seeing quite a few problems with the latest release of our software.
I'm getting customer complaints about crashes. Unfortunately though, I can't get any information from the crash reports. Here is one I receive the most:

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** error for object 0x610000039720: Heap corruption detected, free list canary is damaged


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010444c866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010455735c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000104380b1a abort + 125
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001044ccbee nanozone_error + 486
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001044ccdb0 _nano_malloc_check_clear + 445
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001044cb6b0 nano_malloc + 35
6   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001044c9868 malloc_zone_malloc + 71
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000103e63fed _CFRuntimeCreateInstance + 253
8   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x0000000104a45d70 CGTypeCreateInstance +   79
9   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x0000000104a45c25     region_create_with_shape + 37
10  com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x0000000104a6c0d1 CGSNewEmptyRegion + 24
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x0000000100570ae2 -[NSView _regionForOpaqueDescendants:forMove:] + 4090
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001005706eb -[NSView _regionForOpaqueDescendants:forMove:] + 3075
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001005706eb -[NSView _regionForOpaqueDescendants:forMove:] + 3075
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001005706eb -[NSView _regionForOpaqueDescendants:forMove:] + 3075
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001005706eb -[NSView _regionForOpaqueDescendants:forMove:] + 3075
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001005706eb -[NSView _regionForOpaqueDescendants:forMove:] + 3075
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010069b59d -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 1010
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010069903c -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 3199
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x0000000100699bc4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 6151
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x0000000100699bc4 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 6151
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x0000000100697eb1 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 314
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x0000000100694e9f -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2828
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001006742da -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1680
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001006d974e _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints + 884
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x0000000100caf061 __83-[NSWindow _postWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraintsUnlessPostingDisabled]_block_invoke1331 + 46
26  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000103edfd67 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000103edfcd7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000103ed13b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 776
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000103ed0e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
30  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x0000000109bd2a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
31  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x0000000109bd27b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
32  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x0000000109bd25bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010053d24e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010053c89b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010053099c -[NSApplication run] + 553
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x000000010051b783 NSApplicationMain + 940
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001042b65fd start + 1
```

The odd thing is that in the piece of code that produces the crash, the application is not doing anything. It's almost completely idle sitting there and waiting. This really makes it look like a memory corruption issue.

I've tried and profiled with Instruments to find any leaks. I also tried Xcode 7's new address sanitizer. To no avail.

Can anyone please give me a hint on what I could try to fix the issue?
I'm pretty sure that the issue only appears with release builds but I still couldn't pin down the reason of the crashes.

Comment: Can you include OS X version? If it's El Cap -> you can hope for bug fix or fill a bug report. Also try to turn on address sanitizer in XCode7 (valgrind)

Comment: Nope, the error appears on 10.8+. Most users reporting the bug are on 10.9 and 10.10

Comment: Are those people on 10.8.5/10.9.5/10.10.5 or specific version?

Comment: Also which OS X did you use last time you compiled project. Try to compile it on Mavericks (not Yosemite)

Comment: It has been a few years, but the best tool I've ever used for memory debugging is Valgrind...especially in cases where the corruption's cause seemed unpredictable.  (http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html)